# FreeForm PRO checkbox requied field

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am using FreeForm PRO with EE 2.6.1.  I have a form that I only want submitted if the author agrees to the terms and conditions by checking the box.  I tried to make it a required field, but that did not work.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a copy of Freeform Pro on hand, so I don't have the checkbox fieldtype, but with the free version of 4 I was able to accomplish this with the following:

1. I created a field for the checkbox as a text input named "terms" and attached it to my form
2. I added the required="terms" parameter to my {exp:freeform:form} tag.
3. I added a checkbox input with the name="terms" parameter inside my {exp:freeform:form} tag and set it's value to true.

Upon submission, if the checkbox is unchecked it fails as you would expect, and when it is checked it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

What Diemer said above will work, but for a better user experience you will probably want to use some jquery to validate the form. Personally I like [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) for this sort of thing and is very simple to use.

You'll also want to add the required="checkbox_field_name" parameter to your freeform tags just as a backup measure.